# SPDY on WebLogic 11g

Tags: weblogic, spdy

Is there a way of getting SPDY on the WebLogic 11g server? I actually cannot imaging it but I at least had to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe WLS 11g has native SPDY support, but usually in the WLS architecture, we put a load balancer in front of the WLS cluster. Some load balancer vendors have added the SPDY support recently, such as F5 BigIP. Here is the link: [F5 Gets SPeeDY, Enhances BIG-IP](http://www.f5.com/pdf/analyst-reports/esg-brief-f5-spdy.pdf)

Comment: I am new to SPDY, if the load balancer supports SPDY but the underlying servers do not, does it really provide speed improvement/other SPDY benefits?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty), then you have full SPDY support, with additional benefit features such as [transparent SPDY Push](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/06/spdy-we-push/) which - to my knowledge - is not provided by any other vendor and it is the #1 performance improvement for web sites provided by SPDY.

Jetty 9 also provides a full SPDY proxy that can talk SPDY or HTTP to backend servers (so you can use Jetty as you would use F5 as suggested in another response), so you can leverage SPDY Push even if you stick with your server in the backend.

Take also a look to [HAProxy](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/10/jetty-spdy-and-haproxy/), a software load balancer that can terminate SSL and SPDY and forward SPDY transparently to backend servers.